# Peek at `at` output before it completes

Tags: linux, stdout, at

Let's say I run a script with `at` on Linux (example below) that I know is going to take several hours, or maybe even multiple days. I'm accustomed to `at` sending an email with the output of the command once it completes, but what if I wanted to peek at the current output *before* it completes? Let's also assume I've already run the script and forgot to redirect the output using `tail`, `tee` or other similar methods and do not want to stop the script. Is there anyways to do this?

```
drew@anubis:~$ at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> ./myscript.sh
at> <EOT>
job 3 at Sat Jan  7 09:31:00 2017
```

Comment: peak or peek? You want to see what its doing while its doing it?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, Oops. Peek would be what I meant to type. I want to see what it's doing.

Comment: Redirect the script output to a file when you schedule the at job and `tail -f` that file?

Comment: @muru, Let's pretend I've already run the script without using `tail` and don't want to stop it.

Comment: I'd need to test but would modifying the script to use tee, and saving the output to a file, then tailing it work?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, I'm looking for a method of doing this when I've forgotten to redirect the output within the script and don't want to stop the script. I've updated the question with this detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the job has started, and you have some way of obtaining the PID of that job, you could see where `at` is saving the output:

```
$ at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> sleep 10m
at> <EOT>
job 7 at Sat Jan  7 20:18:00 2017
$ pgrep sleep
7582
$ ls -l /proc/7582/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 muru muru 64 Jan  7 20:19 0 -> /var/spool/cron/atjobs/a0000701795998 (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Jan  7 20:19 1 -> /var/spool/cron/atspool/a0000701795998
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Jan  7 20:19 2 -> /var/spool/cron/atspool/a0000701795998
```

As you can see, the output is saved to a temp file, which you can now check:

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/spool/cron/atspool/a0000701795998
Subject: Output from your job        7
To: muru
```

You need `sudo` because the containing directory is not world-accessible (at least on Ubuntu 14.04):

```
$ sudo namei -lx /var/spool/cron/atspool/a0000701795998
f: /var/spool/cron/atspool/a0000701795998
Drwxr-xr-x root     root   /
drwxr-xr-x root     root   var
drwxr-xr-x root     root   spool
drwxr-xr-x root     root   cron
drwxrwx--T daemon   daemon atspool
-rw------- muru     muru   a0000701795998
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero! That worked perfectly!

Comment: I would like to add though, that if you know you're only running one `at` job. You don't even need the PID. You can just run `sudo ls /var/spool/cron/atspool` and it should, in theory be the only file there.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to determine which spool file belongs to your job is to get the job number from `atq`.

```
drew@sokar:~$ atq
38      Tue Jul 10 12:15:00 2018 = drew
```

Convert the job number to hex. e.g. 38 (dec) = 26 (hex).

```
drew@sokar:~$ printf "%x\n" 38
26
```

Your file will be be named Queue letter (99% of the time, it's `a`) followed by 5 digit hex job id (I learned this by looking through the source code of the `at` command).

```
drew@sokar:~$ sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/atspool
total 55968
-rw------- 1 drew drew       49 Feb 16  2017 a0001c017a3cb2
-rw------- 1 drew drew 57297586 Feb 26  2017 a0001e017a7405
-rw------- 1 drew drew     2329 Jul 10 12:21 a0002601856a0f
                                              -----
```

Then you can view the stdout

```
drew@sokar:~$ sudo less /var/spool/cron/atspool/a0002601856a0f
```